# ¿Cómo crear solicitud Post a Firebase desde C#?

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-core

Estoy desarrollando un método para hacer post desde el servidor a la Api de firebase , escribí esto pero me devuelve el siguiente mensaje:

*StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'The request was missing an Authentication Key (FCM Token). Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent*

```
public async Task<bool> PushServer(string token, string uid, string endPoint = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")
{
    bool result = false;
    string respuesta = string.Empty;
    string jsonData = SetContentPush(token);
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

        System.Net.CredentialCache credentialCache = new System.Net.CredentialCache();
        String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes("key=" + EngineData.KeyServer));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", encoded);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(endPoint, new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            respuesta = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            respuesta = response.IsSuccessStatusCode.ToString();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Pude hacerlo desde PostMan este es el código:

```
POST /fcm/send HTTP/1.1
Host: fcm.googleapis.com
Authorization: key= ServerApiKey
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.20.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: dc671f8a-f457-4198-a8f3-436475af542a,0937fc5b-516d-4644-a539-4db5c34d7cd8
Host: fcm.googleapis.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 390
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache

{"notificación":{"title":"Social Wifi","body":"Tienes una nueva notificación en Social Wifi","click_action":"https://www.sudokudetodos.com","icon":"http://www.icons101.com/icons/5/Replacement_Icons_by_creatiVe5/128/Telegram.png"},"to":"Token del Usuario Logeado"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Este codigo funciono perfecto:

```
   public async Task<bool> PushServer(string token, string endPoint = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")
        {
            bool result = false;
            string jsonData = SetContentPush(token);
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, endPoint);
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "key=" + EngineData.KeyServer); 
            request.Content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); 
            HttpResponseMessage resultado = new HttpResponseMessage(); 
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) 
            { 
                resultado = await client.SendAsync(request);
                result = true;
            }
            return result;
        }

        private string  SetContentPush(string token)
        {
            FirebasePush model = new FirebasePush()
            {
                notification = new FirebasePush.Notification() 
                {
                    title = "Social Wifi",
                    body = "Tienes una nueva notificacion en Social Wifi",
                    click_action = "https://www.sudokudetodos.com",
                    icon = "http://www.icons101.com/icons/5/Replacement_Icons_by_creatiVe5/128/Telegram.png"
                },
                to = token
            };
            string resultado = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            return resultado;
        }
```